# Sybase bcp error

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase, bcp, bulk-load

What i want to do is copy a table into a file, truncate the table and copy the data back into the table.

For this, i am using the following two commands:

Out: `bcp TABLE out file.csv -S SERVER -U user -P password -r '\n' -t '^|' -c`
In:  `bcp TABLE in file.csv -S SERVER -U user-P password-r '\n' -t '^|' -c -J iso_1 -b 5000`

This is the error i get:

`CSLIB Message:  - L0/O0/S0/N36/1/0:`
`cs_convert: cslib user api layer: common library error: The result is truncated because the conversion/operation resulted in overflow.`

The interesting part ( for me, at least ) is that i get the error only for rows with the first column being an **ODD number**. From the first 3 million rows, it cuts half of them, all having the first column ( the `PK` ) an odd number.

I tried with different options, but none seem to work: no problem with the `charset` as far as i can tell, there are no huge columns such that they are truncated and it is not the `carriage return` missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** After creating a format-file there are no more errors, but it only copies half of the data back into the table.

**UPDATE:** I managed to create a format file which works and loads all data, but i cannot use it on another server (it works in testing environment, it needs to run in production environment), since it says `Attempt to read an unknown version of bcp format-file.`? I know what this means, but is there any way of finding the correct values of the version?

**SOLVED:** After digging back in the database, it seems that the problem was indeed data inconsistency due to the fact that the `VIEW` used in production to copy the table only copied 25 columns, but the table has 26 columns ( somebody altered the table and i didn't know and hadn't noticed that it happened ). Fixed the `View` and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going out of/into the same server, I recommend you use `bcp` with the native flag.

```
bcp DBNAME..TABLE out file.bcp -SSERVER -Uuser -Ppassword -n
bcp DBNAME..TABLE in file.bcp -SSERVER -Uuser -Ppassword -n -b5000
```

Character mode can get wierd, and I only use it when it is required.

Comment: Hm... now i'm getting: `negative length prefix found in bcp data file`.

Comment: Are you having other issues with your database?  Maybe some inconsistencies?  Maybe I should have asked what problem you are trying to solve by doing the bcp out/truncate/bcp in?

Comment: there are no issues. there are hundreds of millions, maybe billions of insertions and i want to keep only the relevant ones ( the last 8-9 million rows, and store in some file everything that is less relevant ). And i want to make an automatic process that does this. There are no inconsistencies, as i have checked the data. However, there might be problems with the database or the database server, but if it is so, i have to dig deeper to get some results.

Comment: or if there is another way of getting data from a single table and loading it after the table is truncated, i would consider it as a solution to my problem.

Comment: You could always copy the relevant data to work tables, and then truncate.  It would probably be faster overall, you just need to have enough space in the database.

Comment: The error you are seeing is very odd, and I've only heard of it happening with data inconsistency.

Comment: the thing is it may be required for old data to be loaded in the table again. work tables were my initial choice, but unfortunately i cannot use them.